# Error while training opennlp with indian names

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am getting the following response while I am trying to train the opennlp for Indian names.

> $ opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -model en-ner-person.bin -lang en
>   -data en-ner-person.train -encoding UTF-8

```
Indexing events using cutoff of 5

Computing event counts...  java.io.IOException: Found unexpected annotation: <start:PERSON> suresh ###<END>### 61 years
Incorporating indexed data for training...  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.GISTrainer.trainModel(GISTrainer.java:264)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.GIS.trainModel(GIS.java:298)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.GIS.doTrain(GIS.java:83)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.GIS.doTrain(GIS.java:36)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.train(AbstractEventTrainer.java:93)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME.train(NameFinderME.java:337)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.namefind.TokenNameFinderTrainerTool.run(TokenNameFinderTrainerTool.java:229)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CLI.main(CLI.java:224)
```

My training data is in following format,

```
I am <start:PERSON> suresh <END> 61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Kavitha <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> MohannarayanNew <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Single Raj <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> surendhiran.builder <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Veera <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> prem <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> lashwin <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> suresh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> babu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> raja <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> swamy <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Mahendiran <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> prabakar <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> sanjeeeth <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> venkatesh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> antony <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> suresh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> venkatesh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> selvaraju <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Mahendiran <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> sathiya <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> sucithra <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> karthik.s <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Dilip Kumar Moharana <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> prem <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Jaya <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Sathish <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> jack <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> kumar <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> raja <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Veera <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> potter <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Karthi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Azarudeen <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Abhinav <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> sam <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> surendhiranjayaraman <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> venky <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> karthick <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Gopikrishnan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Gopi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Raja Saravanan D <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> karuppu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Karthikeyan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Vinod <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> selladurai <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> dharmendra <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> jino <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Vinod <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Mike <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> jagdish <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Shailesh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Srikanta Kumar Swain <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Sathish <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> babu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> soundaryaindivi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> melmaruvathur <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> raja <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> jayanthy <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> karan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Mohan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> surendhiran <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Gopinath J <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Dilip <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> mogan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> venkatesh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Karthik <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> prem <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> sathiyamoorthi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 I am <start:PERSON> brintha <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> mahi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Dilip <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> prabu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Vijay <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> JAYAN A <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> pappu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> karthik <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Gopinath J <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> karuppu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Rakesh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Karthik D <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Raja Saravanan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 I am <start:PERSON> Raja Saravanan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 
I am <start:PERSON> Methu Karthik <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Vijayakumar S <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Raja Saravanan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 
I am <start:PERSON> sathiyamoorthi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Shakti Kapoor <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> venkat shanmugam <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Ramasamy S <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Abhineet Sinha <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 I am <start:PERSON> moganarangan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Raja Kullayapp <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29
I am <start:PERSON> tamil vanan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Karthik D <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Murugan Murugan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Jegadeesh Kumar <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Babu <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> muurgan murugan <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Ramesh <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> soundarya devi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 I am <start:PERSON> kalai <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Karthik <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Raja <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> shankar shri <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> vignesh iyer <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> Gopi <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
I am <start:PERSON> vignesh iyer <END>   61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
```

Regards,
Jino.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, That was a simple mistake of the word start in small case.

Comment: word start as in use person instead of PERSON?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Do you mean the noun inside the tags has to start with a capital letter, or do you mean the category of the noun has to start with a capital letter?